# Android Datepicker weird behaviour

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have implemented a Date picker as follows:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {



// when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        String strMonth = "";
        if (month == 0) {
            strMonth = "January";
        } else if (month == 1) {
            strMonth = "February";
        } else if (month == 2) {
            strMonth = "March";
        } else if (month == 3) {
            strMonth = "April";
        } else if (month == 4) {
            strMonth = "May";
        } else if (month == 5) {
            strMonth = "June";
        } else if (month == 6) {
            strMonth = "July";
        } else if (month == 7) {
            strMonth = "August";
        } else if (month == 8) {
            strMonth = "September";
        } else if (month == 9) {
            strMonth = "October";
        } else if (month == 10) {
            strMonth = "November";
        } else if (month == 11) {
            strMonth = "December";
        }
        day = selectedDay;

        tvPurchaseDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append(" ").append(strMonth).append(" ").append(year).append(" "));
        tvPurchaseDate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
};
```

The problem that I am having is that the date picker displays the date wrong as shown in the images below.

As the dialog is created:

[image]

If I select a different date:

[image]

Note the date is not the current date (today) and the year displayed on the wheel and the year displayed at the top of the datepicker are completely different. Am I doing anything wrong? I do not understand, because I have used this code before and it worked fine. The date picker is called from within a view flipper. Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

This is how I call the Date picker:

```
private int day, month, year;
```

In my onClick:

```
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```

Then the onCreateDialog() is called (displayed in the code above), all this code is inside the activity that the call is made from.

Comment: What are the params you're passing to `DatePickerDialog` constructor? Are you calling any configuration methods on the dialog afterwards?

Comment: @laalto, I have edited my question. I am not calling any configuration methods on the dialog afterwards. Let me know if your need anything else

Comment: @laalto, Oops, static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it just now, I needed to set the date as today, because the date picker just added the first date it could find and therefore everything displayed wrong. Added the following code in my `onCreate()`

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```